# Python class method returning 'None' in addition to attributes

Tags: python, oop

I was making a simple method that would return a list of a classes attribute values. It works fine but at the end of the list being printed there is always 'None' displayed as well. I am not sure why. Any clarification?

Here is my code:
Player Class

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, caps, inventory, caravans):
        self.name = name
        self.caps = caps
        self.inventory = inventory
        self.caravans = caravans
```

Inventory Class and it's methods, I am referring to the list method.

```
class Inventory:
    """Items are stored by value not quantity"""
    def __init__(self, weapons_ammo, meds_chems, armor):
        self.weapons_ammo = weapons_ammo
        self.meds_chems = meds_chems
        self.armor = armor

    def list(self):
        """List all inventory values."""
        print(f'Weapons & Ammo: {self.weapons_ammo}\n'
              f'Meds & Chems: {self.meds_chems}\n'
              f'Armor: {self.armor}')
```

Instances

```
example_inventory = Inventory(5000, 2000, 1500)

example_player = Player('John', 10000, example_inventory, 3)
```

When I run this code:

```
print(example_player.inventory.list())
```

I get:

Weapons & Ammo: 5000
Meds & Chems: 2000
Armor: 1500
None

But when I run it without the print function:

```
example_player.inventory.list()
```

I get the proper return I was looking for with the 'None' at the end.

Could anyone explain why this is? I'm assuming it has to do with the method already calling the print function.

Thank you!

Comment: `.list()` **only** returns `None`, it doesn't return anything else. It *prints* something, though.

Answer (score 2):

You specifically `print`ed the return value of the function:

```
print(example_player.inventory.list())
```

Your `list` function has no explicit return; the default value is `None`.  This has nothing to do with having another `print` insides the function, merely that you didn't return anything.

I think that all you want to do is to *execute* the function:

```
example_player.inventory.list()
```

---

BTW, it's very bad form to "shadow" a built-in type: don't use `list` as a function name.  Something such as `show_inventory` would be better.

Comment: If OP isn't planning on needing any other information display functions for the Inventory class, they might consider implementing `__str__` so they can simply `print(example_player.inventory)`.

Comment: Conversely, if OP will need to deal with the contents of the inventory, they might consider implementing `__iter__` so they can go `for item in eample_player.inventory` and possibly `__getitem__` and potentially `__setitem__` etc

Comment: Both are good additions to my beginning suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

`print(example_player.inventory.list())` prints the return value of the `example_player.inventory.list()` method; since there's no `return` statement in the method, the return value is `None`.

The `print` inside the method prints "Weapons & Ammo: 5000 Meds & Chems: 2000 Armor: 1500" and then the `print` outside prints "None"